# RTK Mutations are using different token to queries

Tags: rtk-query

I have a Laravel project with a Reactjs front end. I'm using Redux with RTK Query successfully to fetch data, but when I try a mutation, laravel is returning a 419 error.

Looking at the requests in Telescope, I see the same headers in both the successful and 419 requests, except that the 419 is using a different token to the others.

Here's my code:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
    }),
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getTransactions: builder.query({
            query: () => 'api/transactions'
        }),
        deleteTransaction: builder.mutation({
            query: transactionId => ({
                url: `api/transactions/${transactionId}/delete`,
                method: 'PATCH',
            }),
        }),
        getAccounts: builder.query({
            query: () => 'api/accounts'
        }),
        getPayees: builder.query({
            query: () => 'api/payees'
        }),
        getSpents: builder.query({
            query: () => 'api/spents'
        }),
        getInvestments: builder.query({
            query: () => 'api/investments'
        }),
    })
})

export const { useGetTransactionsQuery, useDeleteTransactionMutation, 
    useGetAccountsQuery, useGetPayeesQuery, useGetSpentsQuery, useGetInvestmentsQuery } = apiSlice;

export const useGetAccountQuery = (accountId) => {
    return useGetAccountsQuery(undefined, {select: (accounts) => accounts[accountId]});
};

export const useGetPayeeQuery = (payeeId) => {
    return useGetPayeesQuery(undefined, {select: (payees) => payees[payeeId]});
};

export const useGetSpentQuery = (spentId) => {
    return useGetSpentsQuery(undefined, {select: (spents) => spents[spentId]});
};

export const useGetInvestmentQuery = (investmentId) => {
    return useGetInvestmentsQuery(undefined, {select: (investments) => investments[investmentId]});
};
```

How can I get the mutation to use the same token as the queries? And why isn't it already?

Comment: What token(s) are you referring to?

Comment: Hi Drew. Are you the resident RTK expert? I mean for sessions. Is there another kind of token? The 419 error is (usually) due to token mismatch, apparently. Certainly in this case it seems true.

Comment: There are many different kinds of tokens. I mean, normally, a "token" is attached to the out-going fetch requests, but here you are using the base `fetchBaseQuery` function and not setting any custom headers, payload/bodies, etc.

Comment: Until now I've never had to worry about it. Inertia has handled the token automatically. The GET queries work as is, and they seem to use the correct token even though they apparently don't need it. I've found a sample on how to switch to using axios instead, so I'll give that a go. If that doesn't work, I'll need to keep digging to find where the token is stored so I can add it to the headers, but so far I haven't found it or any documentation on where to find it.

Comment: Using axios worked. I'll add code below.

Comment: Interesting, so basically just switching from `fetch` to `axios` allows the Inertia library to correctly attach tokens?

Comment: Apparently. There's still so much I don't understand. I'm sure I'll have another question in the next 24 hours. I'm currently struggling with tags and updating single entries in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are other ways to resolve this, but I found that configuring RTK Query to use axios worked and was a simple solution. Here's the new code taken from the tutorial at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#axios-basequery.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const axiosBaseQuery =
    ({ baseUrl } = { baseUrl: '' }) =>
    async ({ url, method, data, params }) => {
        try {
            const result = await axios({ url: baseUrl + url, method, data, params })
            return { data: result.data }
        } catch (axiosError) {
            let err = axiosError
            return {
                error: {
                    status: err.response?.status,
                    data: err.response?.data || err.message,
                },
            }
        }
    }

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
    }),
    endpoints(build) {
        return {
            getTransactions: build.query({
                query: () => ({
                    url: '/api/transactions',
                    method: 'get'
                }),
            }),
            deleteTransaction: build.mutation({
                query: (transactionId) => ({
                    url: `/api/transactions/${transactionId}/delete`,
                    method: 'patch'
                }),
            }),
            getAccounts: build.query({
                query: () => ({
                    url: '/api/accounts',
                    method: 'get'
                })
            }),
            getSpents: build.query({
                query: () => ({
                    url: '/api/spents',
                    method: 'get'
                })
            }),
            getPayees: build.query({
                query: () => ({
                    url: '/api/payees',
                    method: 'get'
                })
            }),
            getInvestments: build.query({
                query: () => ({
                    url: '/api/investments',
                    method: 'get'
                })
            }),
        }
    },
})

export const { useGetTransactionsQuery, useFindTransactionsQuery, useDeleteTransactionMutation, useUndeleteTransactionMutation,
    useGetAccountsQuery, useGetPayeesQuery, useGetSpentsQuery, useGetInvestmentsQuery } = apiSlice;

export const useGetAccountQuery = (accountId) => {
    return useGetAccountsQuery(undefined, {select: (accounts) => accounts[accountId]});
};

export const useGetPayeeQuery = (payeeId) => {
    return useGetPayeesQuery(undefined, {select: (payees) => payees[payeeId]});
};

export const useGetSpentQuery = (spentId) => {
    return useGetSpentsQuery(undefined, {select: (spents) => spents[spentId]});
};

export const useGetInvestmentQuery = (investmentId) => {
    return useGetInvestmentsQuery(undefined, {select: (investments) => investments[investmentId]});
};
```